# Print command with multiple update statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am trying to run multiple updates, with a message printed after each one so I can keep track of any errors. The issue I'm having is that if it fails on say the third update, it throws just the error, and none of my messages go through for the successful updates. How would I go about having the query run the print after each update statement, without putting 'GO' after each one? (I want to be able to collapse the included piece as one region)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION --CUSTOMERS

SELECT *INTO #T FROM CUST where cus_pk !=1
ALTER TABLE #T ADD NEW_PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(50955001,1000)

UPDATE P
SET P.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM PRUDUCT P
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= P.CUS_FK
PRINT'UPDATED PRODUCT CUS_FK'

UPDATE I
SET I.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM ITEMS I
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= I.CUS_FK
PRINT'UPDATED ITEMS CUS_FK'

UPDATE A
SET A.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM ACCT A
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= A.CUS_FK
PRINT'UPDATED ACCT_FK'

UPDATE S
SET S.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM SOLD S
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= S.CUS_FK
PRINT'UPDATED SOLD CUS_FK'

UPDATE c
SET C.CUS_PK= T.NEW_PK
FROM CUST C
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= C.CUS_PK
PRINT'UPDATED CUST CUS_PK'

DROP TABLE #T
ALTER TABLE CUST NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_CUST_LOOKUP_C3
ALTER TABLE CUST NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_CUST_LOOKUP_C5

INSERT INTO CUST SELECT * FROM [DATABSE2].DBO.cust where cus_pk != 1

ALTER TABLE CUST CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_CUST_LOOKUP_C3
ALTER TABLE CUST CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_CUST_LOOKUP_C5
PRINT'NEW CUSTOMERS ADDED'
GO
```

Comment: stop including irrelevant tags

Comment: If you let me know which tag it is, I will gladly remove it.

Comment: have already removed it. it was `mysql`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am still new to scripting, is this T-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes putting `GO` is the way. Also, you should include statement terminator `;` after end of each SQL statement like

```
UPDATE P
SET P.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM PRUDUCT P
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= P.CUS_FK;
PRINT'UPDATED PRODUCT CUS_FK';

UPDATE I
SET I.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM ITEMS I
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= I.CUS_FK;
PRINT'UPDATED ITEMS CUS_FK';
```

Again, instead of using `PRINT` statement you can consider using a `SELECT` statement like

```
UPDATE I
SET I.CUS_FK= T.NEW_PK
FROM ITEMS I
JOIN #T T ON T.CUS_PK= I.CUS_FK;
SELECT 'UPDATED ITEMS CUS_FK';
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help. I was hoping there would be another way around this, I still have a few hundred lines to write, and was trying to organize the chucks with regions. I will start including terminators, thank you again.